# C# 2010 WebBrowser Control doesn't work on Win7-64 with 'Any CPU'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

I created a new VS2010 C# WinForm project, .NET4, added a WebBrowser control with the following code when the form loads:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string strPdfFile = @"C:\RK_ERP\quote\2014-02-014.pdf";
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(strPdfFile);
}
```

Under the Build Tab, if I set the Platform Target: to x86 (That was the default), it works on Win7-32 & Win7-64 machines. If I set Platform Target to Any CPU, it only works on Win7-32. It won't display the PDF on the Win7-64 machines. I've tested on Win7-64 machines with IE 9&10 installed.

The Configuration Platform: is Active(x86). I can't change that for some reason.

This is being done in an effort to fix the same problem in a large ERP project. The retesting if I switch 'Platform Target' would be huge, so I'd like to avoid that. I'm developing currently on a Win7-32 machine.

Comment: What PDF reader is installed on the client? Using a WebBrowser control to host a PDF seems like a massive hack to me...

Comment: You cannot host 32-bit Acrobat in a 64-bit process.  Either install a 64-bit Acrobat plugin (if one exists) or switch to x86.

Comment: Adobe XI is installed. It's done in a form as there are some other button controls on the form. The WebBrowser is just for viewing the PDF prior to taking action. It's been working since 2009. It's just when we started intalling on Win7-64 that we are seeing this issue.